# Subversion, I'm working on a svn. Command to list particular type of files

Tags: svn, visualsvn

Subversion, I'm working on a svn, is there any command/method to make a list of all files with same extension in repository. 
Suppose we have to search in root directory if there are file with (.sh) extension.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a Bourne-compatible shell and standard Unix `grep`,

```
svn ls -R | grep -F .sh
```

If you are on Windows, maybe replace `grep` with the local replacement (`find`?)

Comment: where should I mention **svn path**?. Can you please elaborate the command for windows user.?

Comment: You would run this in the root directory of your repo.  I don't think I can tell you anything you cannot find out yourself with `find /?` but probably `svn ls -R | find ".sh"`

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, I can highly recommend using [GNU on Windows](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki). Then you can do as [triplee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/874188/tripleee) mentions:

```
svn ls -R | grep "\.sh$"
```

Otherwise, you have to resort to `findstr` (`findstr /?`) or `find` (`find /?`).

Run this from the root of your working directory or specify a path (or URL):

```
svn ls -R <path> | grep "\.sh$"
```

where `<path>` should be replaced by the actual path on the file system or a URL to your repository.

Comment: it is not working with **Apache-Subversion**. I'm getting error while using the second cmd mentioned by you 

'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @RAMWorld: Did you install [GNU on Windows](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki) and made sure the utilities are in your PATH? If not, use `findstr "\.sh$"` instead.